# Why Column Viti Is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, return

I want Viti column to have value 1 if @semestri is < 2 and so on but instead of that I got nulls

[image: Photo of Code]

I am new in sql server Thanks for answers

Comment: And once you fix all your problems, how do you expect to debug your code if you do not include the column you are passing to the function? And good debugging practices involving tables start with including the PK values of your table so you know specifically which rows are producing good/bad information.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but your code has lots of issues.

- A function returns `varchar` without a length.  *Always* include a length with strings in SQL Server.
- The function returns a string but the return values are all ints.
- `@viti` is passed in, but is never used.
- The subquery will never have a match, because the `where` clause has an uninitialized variable.  This is where your `NULL` values comes along.

In addition, I'm pretty sure you can do whatever you want with a `case` expression, which would simplify the code.